# .Net javascript shared enum

Tags: javascript, .net, enums

Is there a way to share an enum between Code behind .Net (VB or C#) and javascript so they both use the same values?

can we register an enum into the clientScript..?

**Edit:**
The question is:
Is there a way to share a variable that act like an enum in .Net and do the same job in javascript. I could declare both in javascript and .Net but if someone modify the code later and juste change it in 1 place, everything will blow up...
This is why I am looking for somehting "shared"

Thanks

Comment: Javascript doesn't have enumerations as such. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: yes they do?  http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/10/using-enum-in-javascript/

Comment: From the article you just linked to: "There is no actual ENUM type in JavaScript but there are was that we can get close.". Those are all normal Javascript objects.

Comment: it's not called "enum" but it do exactly the same job. So the question is: can we share a variable that could act as an enum in .Net and do the same job in javascript

Comment: I don't think there's anything inbuilt, but you could probably write an extension method to convert your enum into javascript form as a string and then register that script on your pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//The type of enum we want to use
var enm = typeof(AcceptRejectRule); //or any other enum

//Create the javascript string
var str = "var " + enm.Name + " = {\n" +
        String.Join(",\n", 
               Enum.GetValues(enm).Cast<object>()
               .Select (o => Enum.GetName(enm, o) + ": " + ((int)o))) +
        "\n};";

//Register the javascript to the page for rendering     
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), enm.Name, str, true);
```

Comment: i'll test it before put my vote but it look like what i was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a .NET enum mirrored in javascript:

C#:

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

JS:

```
var Days = {
    Sat: 0,
    ...
    Fri: 6
};
```

Note that this is just an object named `Days` with properties that have numeric values. There is no language implementation of an `Enum` in javascript.

If you want something to automagically convert your C# enum to javascript, just use [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) to iterate over the C# enum and inject it as a javascript object declaration. It boils down to string concatenation, there is nothing in the .NET framework to do this for you.

Comment: The question is how to _share_ one enumeration between the languages, not how to express it in both.

Comment: @Oded what does "share an enum" mean?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to have the enum defined in .NET and generate and use a javascript equivalent from it.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but thought I would share my solution as well:

```
public enum UpdateOptions
{
    Create = 0,
    Read,
    Update,
    Delete,
    None
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ToJSLiteral<UpdateOptions>());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string ToJSLiteral<T>() where T : struct
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int[] values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<int>().ToArray();
        sb.Append("var " + type.Name + " = {\n");

        foreach(int value in values)
        {
            string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            sb.Append(name + " : " + value + ",\n");
        }

        sb.Length -= 2;
        sb.Append("\n};");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```